# RDD actions like first(), head(), isEmpty().. , do they evaluate whole of an RDD? or just parts of it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, lazy-evaluation

I have an RDD, `groupResultMap`, and write a code below.

```
if (groupResultMap.isEmpty) Map[String, Any]()
else  groupResultMap.mapPartitions ( //do somthing// ).collectAsMap
```

In the code, the RDD will be evaluated twice if it is not empty. 
Do you guys think the performance will be better if I put `groupResultMap.cache()` to avoid the redundant evaluations when the RDD is not empty?

Does the RDD's evaluation by `isEmpty()` result in the same as that of `collectAsMap()`?
Or `isEmpty()` evaluate only the part that the action required?
You know, evaluation of only one row of RDD will be enough to calculate the result of `isEmpty()`

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the implementation of isEmpty, it indeed takes one row of the RDD and checks if it is present.

```
def isEmpty(): Boolean = partitions.length == 0 || take(1).length == 0
```

See here: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/4074/files#diff-1d55e54678eff2076263f2fe36150c17

Thus, no - evaluation by isEmpty is not the same as doing collectAsMap. isEmpty is much more efficient than doing a collectAsMap and checking against the length of the map, as it only evaluates the RDD partially, as required.